# Microsoft SQL Performance Counter update rate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try to get the TPS of an MSSQL database.
I'm using this query to retrieve the performance counter values:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'SQLServer:Databases'
AND counter_name = 'Transactions/sec'
AND instance_name = 'DB_NAME'
```

But the update rate is very low. Once a minute or so.
Also it says "Transactions/sec" but the value in
"cntr_value" is very high and increases slowly (5-10 /minute).

```
object_name > SQLServer:Databases   
counter_name > Transactions/sec  
instance_name > DB_NAME   
cntr_value > 4258268   
cntr_type > 272696576
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You can use PerfMon to measure Transactions per Seconds if you want a real time view?

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-performance-counters-transact-sql), you have to take the cntr_type into account in order to interpret the value properly. In this case, it is an accumulating counter. That is, it's incrementing with each transaction. So, to get transactions/sec, you need to take two observations at different times and take a quotient of the difference in observations and the difference in the times. For example, if I observed a value of 10 at T-minus zero and 20 at T-plus five seconds, I'd calculate an average transactions/sec (TPS) of (20-10)/(5-0) = 10/5 = 2 TPS.